# getObjectById throws ClassNotResolvedException

Tags: java, mysql, jdo, datanucleus

We are using mySQL + JDO + Datanucleus.

When I call pm.getObjectById(type,id); it throws the exception

```
javax.jdo.JDOUserException: Failed to find the object of with id "org.geppetto.persistence.db.model.GeppettoProject:1"
NestedThrowables:
org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotResolvedException: Class "org.geppetto.persistence.db.model.GeppettoProject" was not found in the CLASSPATH. Please check your specification and your CLASSPATH.
```

However if before calling it I query the database with something like the following

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(GeppettoProject.class);
query.execute();
```

then from that moment on `getObjectById` starts returning the object. Is this behaviour correct? `getObjectById` seems to only return things once they are cached, i.e. only after a query was executed.
In general I wouldn't like to have to bother with this, if things have to be fetched for the first time then let it be, if they were already fetched give me whatever is cached but I wouldn't expect to have to know about it. Am I missing something?

Comment: if providing an exception, it is normal to show the stack trace

Comment: plus code that shows both behaviours - the problem may, for example, be in your setup rather than the three lines of code provided here.

Comment: you seemingly must have resolved what you were doing wrong